# Google Play Developer Console - An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later

Tags: android, google-play, rating, developer-console

I'm trying to reply to users who have just provided ratings, however, from past 2 weeks I'm facing this error and I'm unable to successfully open the link.

Are you facing this error or I'm the only one that is targeted by Google ?

Help me to provide users the required support!

[image: GPDC Error]

Comment: Hi, I am also getting this error, Have your found any solution ?

Comment: I had emailed Google Play Store support and they said that they have closed this feature. So there is no solution

Comment: I can't able to open any link in Google Play developer console due to this error.  have you able to open any link in developer console? how can i avoid this error?

Comment: Links means tabs like statistics, In-App products, Store Listing etc.

Comment: It is working for me as of now. Check your internet connection.

Comment: I ran into this issue too. Very random but the issue persists. After so many years it still exists

Answer (score 31):

After July 2020  google has updated the play console and redirected on [this url](https://play.google.com/console) If you have not redirected automatically to the above link then manually open this link.

Comment: just ran into this now and thought I was going mad. They are not redirecting so this sorted me out. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Crazy that they'd give us such a generic error message instead of providing the new URL..

Comment: Life Saver !! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a gift from google to devs boiling in release train rush.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you only have a google account started in the browser

Comment: What exactly does this mean?

Comment: This helped on my case, at least.  The error happened when I signed in to Chrome using my personal google account and tried to open play console under a company account (we use G-Suite of course).  To fix this, simply open incognito mode and sign in using the account that play console belongs to.  By the way, the error code was 8869003.

Answer (score 3):

Google Developers Testing New Play Console In Beta Version

[image]

Visit
https://play.google.com/console/developers

Then sign in From Your Account
Use The New Play Console :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error.

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later. (7)

The message here is obviously unhelpful. I contacted Google Play support about it and this is their response:

> Due to some updates, only authorized users with the access of "***Edit store listing, pricing & distribution***" are able to edit content ratings page.
>
> If you are the account owner, you can grant user permissions either at the account level or at the individual app level. To add a user at the app level, please follow these steps:
>    1. Sign in to your Play Console.
>    2. On the left menu, click *Settings > Developer account > Users & permissions*.
>    2.a. To add a new user, click “Invite new user” and type in the user’s email address.
>    2.b. To update permissions for an existing user, click the gear icon on the right and select "Change permissions."
>    3. Don't choose a predefined role from the "Role" drop-down.
>    4. Instead, add your app to the per-app permissions table with the "Add an App" drop-down.
>    5. Check the boxes in the appropriate column to add user permissions to specific apps.
>    5.a. For full functionality, some permissions need to be set to "Global." For more information, review the permission definitions table.
>    6. Click Send Invitation.

TL;DR: You need ***Edit store listing, pricing & distribution*** permissions on the app.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to go to the console -> Store Presence -> Pricing & Distribution -> Click on Country -> REFRESH EXCHANGE RATES -> Save. Than Complete the Content rating and it is now saved.

Answer (score 0):

From July, 2020

Try the new link for Google Play Console

https://play.google.com/console

Answer (score 0):

This was happening for me due to using another google account on chrome than the default. Using an incognito browser fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I logged in using InCognito mode and it worked

Comment: This is the same solution as in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66388139/2227743).