# Google Play Console unhelpful error message

Tags: android, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload a new version of an android app on Google play console, but as soon as I select the app it gives me:
"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later."

No other information is provided, and it worked 3 days ago. Is there anything that could be wrong on my end or did google just break their interface somehow?

(I'm using google chrome on unbuntu 18)

Comment: We are experiencing the same issue starting this morning. They probably have some server problems.

Comment: Same here!  Worked yesterday...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Play Developer Console - An unexpected occurred. Please try again later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33629371/google-play-developer-console-an-unexpected-occurred-please-try-again-later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use new version of the console (https://play.google.com/console)  to upload new version of your app.

Comment: The old console seems to be having issues today, but the new one allows for browsing and submitting apps, as far I know.

Comment: Experiencing this even when trying to promote a release from Beta to Production on the new Console. Anyone has a different experience?

Comment: After days of not been able to upload APK to the play store. The new https://play.google.com/console works well for APK  upload. The old console appears to be buggy

Comment: Its happening again with the "new" play console but I'm getting a 403 in the JS console along with multiple warnings that some `dart.js` file couldn't be found. Signing out and back in, trying on a different internet connection and a different browser did not work.

Answer (score 3):

With some URL hackery you should be able to upload and publish a new version of the app even with the error.

1. Open the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish)
2. Right-click an app and choose "Open in new tab"
3. Replace `AppDashboardPlace` in the URL to a working page like `MarketListingPlace`

I can see the following pages work currently:

- Android vitals > Deobfuscation files
- Development tools > *
- Release management > App releases (incl. tracks and releases)
- Release management > Android Instant Apps
- Release management > Artifact library
- Release management > Device catalog
- Release management > App signing
- Store presence > *
- User acquisition > *
- User feedback > *

It was fine for me 6 hours ago, I now encounter the same problem from Sweden. A few people have reported this problem online for the last 2 weeks.

Private browsing mode in Chrome, Firefox and Safari didn't solve it, no JS console errors or network errors. Circumventing the AJAX request returned a blank page with the same "An unexpected error occurred". I can't see how this could be a client issue.